# React with TypeScript - Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've created a function that fires on button clicks that sets a value to a filter. It works fine however I get the TypeScript error.

`Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.`

Heres my button function that fires onClick:

```js
  const handleFilterButtonChange = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setTerm(event.target.value);
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HTMLButtonElement` generic indicates the element the listener is attached to, but said element is not necessarily the target. See here for an example:

```js
const handleFilterButtonChange = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target);
};
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', handleFilterButtonChange);
```

```html
<div>
  <button>click</button>
</div>
```

Above, the listener is attached to the `<div>`, but the `event.target` is the button, since the button was the innermost element clicked.

That's why TypeScript is giving you a warning. Use `.currentTarget` instead, which will refer to the element the listener is attached to:

```
const handleFilterButtonChange = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setTerm(event.currentTarget.value);
};
```